# how to combine two red black tree efficiently

Tags: java, complexity-theory, red-black-tree

> Two left-leaning red-black trees, T1 and T2, with n<sub>1</sub> entries in T1, n<sub>2</sub> entries in T2, all the entries in the T1 are less than entries in T2, find a way to combine these two trees with O(log n1 + log n2) complexity.

Any one have any idea, totally no clue.

Comment: Looks like exercise. Show your attempts and we will help you on that basis.

Comment: you are sharp to find out that,it is from an exercise, my attempt is trying to find the minimum node x in T2, which takes logn2 time, then connect the root of T1 directly to x.left, this takes constant time, then any rotate left/ right and flip colors , I am pretty sure it is the right way, but I am confused going into details how the rotation/ color flip takes time relating logn1,

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible. To perform some, even very simple, action over `N` elements (`n2` for your case, you need `O(n2)` **minimum**). So, I think you have to do normal adds and you'll get `O(N * log(N))` complexity.